# Ad Dlo Yoda  measurments

Tags: purim, shiurim-measurements

What are the many Halachic options of doing the Mitzvah of drinking on Purim please quote sources? Meaning what are the diffrent the definitions of ad Dlo Yoda?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. "Ad delo yada" is not accepted as halachah at all. (Taz, Orach Chaim 695:2)
2. It means to drink enough that you sleep, and then you don't know the difference between "cursed is Haman" and "blessed is Mordechai." (Maharil, cited in Rema there)
3. Which is the greater benefit that Hashem granted us: that Haman was degraded and executed, or that Mordechai was elevated? Go back and forth praising Hashem for this so much that you lose track of which one is more important. (Taz ibid. :1)
4. Reach a state where you can't calculate that ארור המן = ברוך מרדכי in gematria. (Magen Avraham ibid. :3)
5. It means "ad" - "up to" the point where you might get confused, but don't cross that line, because then you won't be able to properly thank Hashem for the miracle. (Yad Ephraim)
6. There was an old piyut that told over the story of Purim in rhyme, with alternating refrains of ארור המן and ברוך מרדכי. Reach the point where you lose track of which verse you're up to. (Aruch Hashulchan 695:3)

Comment: Thanx, and again amazing answer as Usual

Comment: 4,5&6 would allow for being pretty drunk...

Answer (score 3):

Get drunk enough that you are not mentally competent enough to be included in the command to drink.  Ad d'lo yada is the point at which you are in a temporary state of being exempt from the *mitzvah* because you are drunk.  If you sober up, get right back in there, buddy! (Emek Beracha quoting R' Yisrael Salanter)

Comment: This would fit with the sleeping explanation.

Comment: Is he quoting if I recall he is citing a story.

Comment: @mevaqesh I don't have it in front of me but I think he starts with שמעתי בשם... oh wait, I have it somewhere on my harddrive... yes it stars with שמעתי בשם הגאון ר' ישראל סלנטר ז"ל

Comment: @DoubleAA he cites that Rambam, along with another diyuk from the Rambam - he says the Rambam wrote יאכל בשר but שותה יין, in לשון הווה, because the drinking is not just one and done, but it is ongoing.  Then he brings the sleeping bit.

Comment: Nitpicky, but I would call that citing something heard rather than quoting.

Answer (score 2):

Additional answers:

1) No **obligation** but just a good thing: (Raavya; vol. 2 ch. 564, Hagahos Mainonis; Hil. Purim 2:15, Maharil; responsum 56 citing Maharash, in turn cited by Darchei Moshe, and other acharonim).

2) It is merely an exaggerated expression (Meoros to Megillah 7b).