# Ad delo yada and being asleep how does it work?

Tags: halacha, purim, sleep

As we know a person sleeping is פטור מן המצוות exempt from mitzvos. So how can it be – as the Rema states famously – that while you are asleep you fulfill עד דלא ידע  (having drunk until he doesn't know; his wording is "umetoch sheyashen eino yodeya bein arur haman lebaruch mordechai", "and from the fact that he sleeps, he doesn't know"). How, according to this Rema, can a sleeper who has no knowledge actively fulfill the requirement?

Comment: See comments on [this answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/26348). Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12034.

Comment: A sleeper is exempt from mitzvos, but besides for the real answer (below) about Rama's intent, we can further note that this isnt a mitzva but a mere good deed see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6395/ad-dlo-yoda-measurments/53489#53489) that this is the opinion of Raavya, Maharil, et al. The formal exemption from mitzvos would thus have no bearing on this informal act.

Comment: In addition to @mevaqesh's point, it's not at all clear to me that "exempt from" is the same as "unable to fulfill," for *mitzvot* and certainly for "nice practices."

Answer (score 5):

He fulfills the obligation by going to sleep and actively entering a state of not knowing.

Comment: How do you interpret the words of the Rema? METOCH SHEYOSHEN. through his sleep he has no knowledge. I understand that this answer posited. But I am actively ignoring it based on the words of the Rema

Comment: Also someone who is drunk cannot fulfill an obligation because he has no daas. The gemara says ad delo yada which is fulfilled by the act you took to get to that state, either drinking or sleeping.

Comment: answers with sources are often rated the highest on this forum

Comment: Ignore it or dont but this is the true right answer. Through sleep one fulfills his obligation. That is his requirement is to drink and sleep. וא"ת we have no obligations to sleep for sleeper (you assume) are not commanded in mitzvos, in reality there is a mitzva to sleep in a sukka as part of living. This is explained by R. SZ Aurbach as  an obligatin to *go to sleep*,(he holds that once asleep if one is removed from the succa there is no problem becauuse the mitzva is to go to sleep).

Comment: @mevaqesh That rav shlomo zalman is the basis of my question.  So since being asleep and unaware. That state is where the kiyum mitzvah is. If so how can you be mekayem a mitzvah without daas. The kiyum is not to bring yourself but rather to BE in that state.

Comment: @mevaqesh I suggest to reread that rav shlomo zalman who says that mitzvah if sleeping in sukka is to go to sleep but to sleep. Thus you can pull him out. Purim is different that sukka. What is your basis to compare the two?

Comment: The chiyuv as stated in the gemara chayav inish lebesumei a person is obligated to drink ... So the obligation is the act ad delo yada is the shiur.

Comment: @Nafkamina besides for my point in the other comment that drinking on prim is a meritorious act rather than a mitzvah from which one would be exempted asleep, my point was that one can have a mandate to go to sleep as for example we find by succah. So to by Purim (even if there was a mandate) we could understand it to be to go to sleep rather than to be asleep.

Comment: How do you actively go to sleep?

Comment: @DoubleAA i dont understand, do you always just konk out  without lying down or closing your eyes, you dont say krias shema al hamita, get into pajamas? etc.. i would classify those things as actively going to sleep